# Getting Node.js/Geddy app set up with CoffeeScript support

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, geddy

Just getting started with Node.js and I'm using the Geddy framework (I like the similarity to Rails). But I'm having some trouble getting it to work properly with CoffeeScript. I see [Geddy is now "supporting" coffee files](https://github.com/mde/geddy/pull/150). But when I start converting even the default js to coffee, I get errors:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/geddy/lib/app.js:108
      ctor.origPrototype = ctor.prototype;
                               ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
at _registerControllers (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/geddy/lib/app.js:108:36)
at async.AsyncBase.runItem (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/geddy/node_modules/utilities/lib/async.js:108:10)
at async.AsyncBase.next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/geddy/node_modules/utilities/lib/async.js:113:12)
at async.AsyncBase.execCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/geddy/node_modules/utilities/lib/async.js:148:54)
at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

I have CoffeeScript installed, but I don't really know what else I'm supposed to do here. The documentation on this is pretty much non-existant.

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: Try search issues https://github.com/mde/geddy/issues , wiki 
https://github.com/mde/geddy/wiki/_pages

Comment: Thanks, Paul. I've already looked through it, no dice.

Comment: Looks like you're not exporting your controller. Maybe paste your code?
Look at the [example](https://github.com/mde/geddy/blob/master/examples/todo_app_coffee/app/controllers/main.coffee)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [geddy-coffee-templates](https://github.com/MiguelMadero/geddy-coffee-templates). You can create a new base app from coffeescript. Adding a model and controller is working now, but the scaffold and resource generators are not working at the moment.

For an existing app, simply add a dependency to `coffee-script` on your `package.json` file. ([Example](https://github.com/MiguelMadero/geddy-coffee-templates/blob/master/templates/base/package.json.ejs)). Then `npm install`.

Answer (score 0):

this question is probably a bit old but I just ran into this problem.

In my case, all I did was added a controller file called fruits.js but inside my fruits.js I defined it as:

```
var Fruit = function () {

...

};

exports.Fruit = Fruit;
```

The problem is in the naming of the file and the actual variable name not matching.

In my case, the simple fix was:

```
either rename "Fruit" to "Fruits"
```

or

```
change the file name from "fruits.js" to "fruit.js"
```

So the lesson learned is Geddy expects the controller file name to match the actual variable definition inside the file.

Hope you were having the same problem.